# HTMLAgilityPack - Get text thats not in a tag

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

```
<a href="/state/details"><span class="state">Queens</span> New York</a>
```

I only want "New York".  How can I accomplish this without getting "Queens" as well?

Comment: If the solution worked, please accept it as answer or upvote. If not - write about it

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use XPath to retrieve info you need from your `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc` variable:

```
    foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/a/text()[last()]"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText.Trim());
    }
```

This selects only New York

Answer (score 0):

Using HtmlAgilityPack you can use LastChild as follows:

```
return (doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault().LastChild.InnerText.Trim())
```

which will return just "New York".